# Destination Path Too Long & how to resolve it?

Tags: windows-7

Whenever I use Windows Explorer to copy Google Drive subfolders, I frequently get the "Destination Path Too Long" error.
Any suggestions how to resolve it?

Comment: You should probably reorganize things so that you're not going so deep, or with shorter names. However, you _may_ be able to "cheat" by mapping a drive to [some portion of] the destination path, and then copying the files to the mapped drive. This has worked for me, though sometimes if the destination is on a network share, it fails.

Comment: "Any suggestions how to resolve it?" - The only real solution is to use shorter paths.  Windows 10 has experimental support for longer paths.

Answer (score 0):

If the subfolders have longer file name, just shorten their name, and copy them.

If the subfolders are too deep, please try the following workaround.

1. copy the subfolders to the root directory or directory that is close to the root directory.
2. copy the subfolders(has been copied to root directory) to where you want.